# Magento 2. Improve performance of UI Grid

Tags: magento2, grid

- I have a UI Grid that uses a collection with multiple joins (~7-8)

  - I know joins are a huge performance drawback. But I would think that pagination fixes the performance issue.
  - From around ~20k rows in my main table the grid loads really slow.

**Questions**

- Does Magento loads all the items despite pagination?
- Is there any way to improve the performance of my grid? (a flat table or an index is not a viable solution in this particular case)

Any pointers are highly appreciated
Thank you.

Comment: Did you got any solution to improve performance?

Comment: Yes. Went with an index table.